# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'uvicorn main:app --reload

Tags: python, cmder, fastapi

Intento ejecutar mi primer `hello world` con `fastapi`. Pero cuando lo ejecuto en la terminal con:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Me aparece este error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'

Agradeceria su ayuda.

Comment: Verificaste que tienes la libreria instalada? Que gestor de paquetes utilizas (pip, poetry, pipenv, etc)?

Comment: Gracias por contestar amigo. Utilice pip

Comment: Y al hacer pip freeze visualizas el paquete dentro de ese listado?

Comment: Si hermano.....